# Using #states with field collection

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use #states in a unlimited field collection (using the field collection module).

I'm adding this functionality to a node add form so am altering form elements using hook_form_alter.

I can get it to work for the first item in the collection using the following code but it doesn't work for items added subsequently.

```
$form[$k]['field_employee_name']['#states'] = array(
    'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="field_witnesses[und][0][field_person_type][und]"]' => array('value' => 'Employee'),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this to work we need to add the #states functionality to every field collection after the ajax callback has taken place.

To do this add an #after_build function to the field collection item in hook_form_alter:

```
$form['field_witnesses'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#after_build'][] = 'field_witnesses_after_build';
```

And then in the after build function loop over the elements to add the #states behavior:

```
function field_witnesses_after_build($form, &$form_state) {
    foreach($form as $k => $v) {
        if(isset($v['#entity_type']) && $v['#entity_type']=='field_collection_item') {

            $form[$k]['field_employee_name']['#states'] = array(
                'visible' => array(
                    ':input[name="field_witnesses[und]['.$k.'][field_person_type][und]"]' => array('value' => 'Moto Employee'),
                ),
            );

        }
    }
    return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for posting this, I was really going crazy trying to make #states work with hook_form_alter and your post saved the day! Just to clarify, I'm going to provide some greater detail about how I got this to work:

1. I created a new content type. It has some of its own fields. I then
   added a field collection to the content type with machine name
   "field_volunteer_jobs".
2. I edited the field collection and added fields for a boolean
   (checkbox) with machine name "field_vol_use_event_date" and a date
   with machine name "field_vol_date".
3. When a person is entering data on the content page, I want the date field to be hidden whenever the checkbox is checked.
4. I created a new module, named "states". In the module, I have the following hooks:

   ```
   function states_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   switch ($form_id) {
   case 'school_event_node_form': 
       $volunteer_jobs_lang = $form['field_volunteer_jobs']['#language'];
       $form['field_volunteer_jobs'][$volunteer_jobs_lang]['#after_build'] = array('states_after_build');
   break;
   }
   }
   function states_after_build($form, &$form_state) { //works!
     foreach($form as $k => $v) {
       if(is_numeric($k) && isset($v['#entity_type']) && $v['#entity_type']=='field_collection_item') {
         $form[$k]['field_vol_date']['#states'] = array(
           'invisible' => array(
           ':input[name="field_volunteer_jobs[und]['. $k.
           '][field_vol_use_event_date][und]"]' => array('checked' => TRUE))
         );
       }
     }
     return $form;
   }
   ```

Note that in the states_after_build code above, I should really query the field #language and use that instead of [und]...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it for fieldset adding an `#id` attribute and set `#states` in `hook_field_group_build_pre_render_alter`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_group_build_pre_render_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_field_group_build_pre_render_alter(&$element) {
  if ($element['#form_id'] === 'MY_FORM' && isset($element['MY_FIELDSET_NAME'])) {
    // Add form states to the field group.
    $element['MY_FIELDSET_NAME']['#id'] = 'MY_FIELDSET_NAME';
    $element['MY_FIELDSET_NAME']['#states'] = [
      'invisible' => [
        ':input[name="CONDITION_FIELD"]' => ['value' => 'CONDITION_VALUE'],
      ],
    ];
  }
}
```